# How to put upper dot to a kannada font in XeLaTeX?

Tags: tex-core, xetex

I'm a beginner in XeLaTeX programming.

I need to put an **upper dot** to some **kannada fonts** in a PDF.

I used the following code snippet to do that. But the output is negative.

Please help me in this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont[Script=Kannada]{Kedage}
\begin{document}

1) ಸ         \\
2) $\dot{ಸ}$ \\
3) \.{ಸ}     \\

\end{document}
```

I get the following result by using XeLaTeX command

1. ಸ
2. only **upper dot** without **ಸ**
3. **ಸ** with an **empty-box** next to it.

Comment: I do not have the font and cannot experiment, but the problem may be 1/ that kannada fonts otf do not support accents and/or 2/ that they are just ignored in math mode. 1/ would explain why \.{ಸ} does not work and 2/ why $\dot{{ಸ}$ gives nothing. But \dot in math mode is able to put a dot over any symbol. You should try \dot, while  outputing the letter in text mode : $\dot{\text{ಸ}}$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion solved my problem.